# Setting initial supply for factory contract generated token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I wrote a factory contract for generating some tokens and it is able to successfully create tokens. However, when I import the generated token address to my wallet, the supply is 0 even though I have set it to a value:

Factory contract snippet:

```
contract TokenFactory {
    event MyTokenCreated(address contractAddress);

    function createNewMyToken() public returns (address) {
        MyToken myToken = new MyToken(2000000);
        emit MyTokenCreated(address(myToken));
        return address(myToken);
    }
```

MyToken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor (uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("MyToken", "MY") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply * 10 ** 18);
    }
}
```

After generating MyToken from TokenFactory and importing the generated token's address to my wallet, I expected the supply to be 2000000, but it is 0.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you link the contract and etherscan transaction so that we may take a deeper look into this?  What I'm seeing is that you call ```MyToken()``` but there is no address being referenced, so my guess is it might be sending it to either the ```0x0``` address or the contract address instead.  I would pass your address as a parameter to your token constructor instead and then call the mint function with that argument and see if that works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are sending tokens to msg.sender, and in this case, the msg.sender will always be the factory contract. So if you want to mint those tokens to your own wallet, you can either give MyToken a new address param where your factory contract will pass your address, or just use tx.origin, so that it references the transaction original creator address.